# How to get a single p-value from the two p-values of a Mardia's multinormality test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis, p-value

I am performing a [Mardia's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Multivariate_normality_tests) to assess the multinormality of a multivariate distribution.

Mardia's test actually perform two tests, one on the skewness and another on the kurtosis, thus yielding two p-values.

Is there a valid way to combine those two p-values into one so that results are easier to share?

I've read about [Fisher's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method) to combine several p-values, but this method assumes independence of the p-values, which is surely not the case here. Is it somehow still valid here?

Comment: The two statistics are not independent; asymptotically they will be but you will require very large sample sizes before it's reasonable to treat them as close to independent. Fisher's method relies on independence.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b! It's what I understood from the link I give in the OP. do you know of any method that might apply in my case?

Comment: Well, you could (a) investigate the dependence in the null case, or (ii) do a each test at the $\alpha/2$ level (sometimes called a "rectangle test"; I wonder if that term is maybe in Bowman and SHenton's paper on the univariate case) -- though both the approximations to the components offered there are *also* large sample approximations that may not be so great if you don't have quite large $n$.

Comment: If you want an omnibus (factotum, portmanteau) test that by Doornik and Hansen seems superior. (Looking at the data carefully could be even better.

Answer (score 0):

Two researchers did exactly what you are asking back in 1973 [[ref 1]](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article/60/3/613/217275). If the skewness statistic is $MS$ and the kurtosis statistic is $MK$, the combined Mardia statistic is

$MSK=MS+|MK|^2$

Here is another reference which details this specific process [[ref 2]](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3927875/). Best of luck!